# Does not show any collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am a beginner in mongodb. 2 days before I created a db named inventory and inserted collection too. But today I want get all collections in Inventory

I typed

```
db.inventory.find()
```

but it didn't show anything... what's the reason?

Comment: Did you do a 'use inventory' to get to the right database?

Comment: no... now I get... , extremely sry for this silly question...

Answer (score 0):

If ur db is inventory just use the following commands

use inventory

show collections

This would list u all the collections u've created inside this db .

db.collection_name.find()

will list u all data(documents) u've created in it

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
use inventory
show collections
```

By default the mongo shell connects to the database `test`. so you have to type `use inventory` to switch to your desired database (`show databases` returns a list of all created databases if you are facing errors with typos). After switching to the correct database type `show collections` to get a list of all created collections in your current database.